# Get application name from session in Fiddler

Tags: windows, communication, fiddler

I need detect application name, that communicate from internet.
Is it possible detecting application from catched communication?

Comment: Unless the application advertises itself using a unique User-Agent string, no. Sadly, historically many web sites did browser feature detection off of User-Agent so now absolutely every web client lies

Comment: Thanks, it is so sad. I'm needed detect any application (that are checking for new version, or send statistic and so..), not browsers.

Comment: Sounds like you could just get your application to identify itself then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually asking about *Fiddler* (which runs locally on your PC), the originating Process Name is shown in a column and is available via the `LocalProcess` property of the Session.